# How Do I Downgrade My OS from High Sierra back to Mavericks?

Tags: macbook-pro

Here's my issue: I recently bought a used 15" Mid 2010 MacBook Pro. I installed my CS6 Master Collection lifetime license on it, and about a month later, I ran into some technical difficulties with Audition. I reached out to Adobe and the "help" I received was to purchase the latest version of the software, as they stated they couldn't guarantee compatibility with my OS.

I instead chose to downgrade to a previous OS; I ran through the boot installation process through the terminal with Apple Care on the line. The process ended up taking approx an hour, but the agent had to end the call prior to the process finishing, but gave me instructions on how to complete the process.

I got to the point where I was asked to choose which disk to boot from, I chose the thumb drive, and I ran into the "prohibited" sign. I repeated the process, same thing; afterwards, I unlocked the thumb drive, and unchecked the ignore ownership box (read it on a forum), and I ran into the same issue.

I then read that another problem could be the OS in which the installer was created on in the first place; to remedy this, I tried a factory reset, but here's the kicker: when at the point of re-installing the factory OS, it actually is UPGRADING to High Sierra, as oppose to the one that came with the MacBook.

It was running Sierra already, and now I can only install High Sierra, and not even continue using Sierra. So

a) I need assistance with actually installing the factory OS, and

b) re-installing the thumb drive installation boot so that I'm able to downgrade my OS so that I'm able to continue using my CS6 MC;

I really need help on this and any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, so how did you get the Maverick OSX installer? how di you create mavericks boot USB disk ?

Comment: The easiest way would be if you have a Time machine back up from Mavericks times.

Comment: I created thru a USB thumb drive... An Apple Care senior advisor walked me thru it